# Check if last character is X, Y or Z

Tags: c#, regex

How can I check if the last character of word matches X, Y or Z

eg:

> park
>
> tanky
>
> spacex

Using `[xyz]` will match any of those characters in the entire string, not just the last one. Is it possible to do this in *pure* regex without having to create a substring?

Comment: `[xyz]$`, this is incredibly basic. Please show what effort you've gone through before posting a question.

Comment: @funkwurm Seriously? Basic or not, I did not know how to do it. I showed my progress too. So what should I do next time? Don't even ask for help since someone might be offended because it's a very basic question? Everyone was a beginner once.

Comment: A quick Google search for _"regex last character"_ gave tutorials, [reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) and stackoverflow questions all mentioning the use of `$` for this. I am not offended, this website only works if questions too specific to be solved with a Google search aren't buried under questions that _are_ this basic. We don't expect you to skip the beginner-phase, we expect you to utilize resources other than someone simply giving you the code before asking a question. Particularly the `regex` tagged questions suffer from this, might explain my tone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to anchor to the end of the string with `$`

```
[xyz]$
```

If you need to do a case insensitive match you can either use the following

```
[xXyYzZ]$
```

Or you can specify that the matching should be case insensitive with `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`.

```
bool match = Regex.IsMatch(input, "[xyz]$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use end of the line anchor `$` to match the character `x` or `y` or `z` present at the last.

```
[xyz]$
```

In regex `[]` called character class. Note that  the char class without any following `*` or `+` would match a single character only. Add `(?i)` case-insensitive modifier in your regex inorder to match both upper and lowercase `x` or `y` or `z` present at the last.

```
@"(?i)[xyz]$"
```

Answer (score 1):

`/[a-wA-W]+([x-zX-Z]{1})/g`

This regex checks all words, not just the line ending. For example this string checks successfully:

park tank**y** rase**z** dasdasd**z** asdasdada**x**yy

You can check it on [REGEX101.com](https://www.regex101.com/)

Comment: the last x shouldnt be bold, but the y should.

Comment: This does not work - the last word ends with 'y' but does not match. Also, a better answer would explain how the regex pattern works.

Comment: ([xyz]{1})(?:\s|$)this works with line endings and whitespaces

Answer (score 1):

Searching for `[XYZ]\b` looks for the letters followed by a word boundary. This will find if a word in a bigger string ends with the letters.

Look for "boundary" on [this web page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)

The answers suggesting searching for `[XYZ]$` will not handle strings such as "IBEX."

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
^\w+[xyz]$
```

it match the whole word.

```
bool match = Regex.IsMatch(input, "^\w+[xyz]$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

[Live Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/vR7hT2/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
([xyz]{1})(?:\s|$)
```

This works with line endings and whitespaces
and checks only the last charecter of word

Answer (score 0):

or you could not use a regex,

```
var valid = new[] { 'x', 'y', 'z' };
return valid.Contains(s.Last());
```